# android - How to check how many elements are present in a GridView?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am dynamically adding images to a GridView.

I want to have a counter to check how many images are present in a GridView.
The purpose is to restrict the user to add maximum of "n" images.

Therefore I want to have a counter which will count this number and I will check accordingly.

```
public class ExistingDetailedActivity extends Activity {
public String images,audiopath,name,assignedTo;
TextView ringtonename,assigned;
public GridView gridView;
public String [] imgpath;
CustomBaseExistAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_existing_detailed);
    Intent i = getIntent();

    if(i.hasExtra("BNDL")){
        Bundle bdl = getIntent().getBundleExtra("BNDL");

        if(bdl.get("IMAGEPATH") != null){
            images = bdl.getString("IMAGEPATH");
        }

        if(bdl.get("AUDIOPATH") != null){
            audiopath = bdl.getString("AUDIOPATH");
        }
        if(bdl.get("RINGTONENAME") != null){
            name = bdl.getString("RINGTONENAME");
        }
        if(bdl.get("ASSIGNEDTO") != null){
            assignedTo = bdl.getString("ASSIGNEDTO");
        }
    }
    Typeface FONT_NAME = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "komika-title-brush-1361511399.ttf");

    imgpath=images.split("\\*") ;

    ringtonename=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ringtonename.setText(name);
    ringtonename.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    ringtonename.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);

    assigned=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    assigned.setText(assignedTo);
    assigned.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    assigned.setTypeface(FONT_NAME);
    gridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

    adapter = new CustomBaseExistAdapter(this,imgpath);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gridView.invalidateViews();
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Another one is

```
public class CustomBaseExistAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private final Activity context;
public String[] imagepath;
private String[] imagepath1=null;
private String[] imagepathBackUp=null;

public CustomBaseExistAdapter(Activity context,
String[] imagepath) {
this.context = context;
this.imagepath = imagepath;

this.imagepathBackUp =imagepath;

List<String> nonBlank = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s: imagepath) {
    if (!s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        nonBlank.add(s);
    }
}
imagepath1 = (String[]) nonBlank.toArray( new String[nonBlank.size()] );

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return imagepath.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
 @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return 0;
    }
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     convertView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_image_with_checkbox, null);
            CheckBox cb=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);

            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int id = buttonView.getId();
                    if(isChecked){

                 /*String newList[] = new String[imagepath.length - 1]; 
                     int count = 0;
                     for (int i = 0; i < imagepath.length; i++) {
                           if (imagepath.length - 1 > 0) {
                              if (imagepath[i] == imagepath1[position]) { // itemPath[1] as the range starts from 0, so 1 would be ITEM2
                              // SKIP IF MATCHES THE ITEM YO WANT TO REMOVE                       
                              } else {
                                  newList[count] = imagepath[i];
                                  count++;
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          imagepath=new String[newList.length];
                     imagepath= newList;*/
                   List<String> newlist= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(imagepath));         
                        newlist.remove(imagepath1[position]);  
                        imagepath=null;
                        imagepath = newlist.toArray(new String[newlist.size()]);
                                /*new String[newlist.size()];
                        for(int j =0;j<newlist.size();j++){
                            imagepath[j] = newlist.get(j);
                        }*/
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }

            });

imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath[position]));      

        }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Fixed some grammar and some formatting

Answer (score 0):

To know number of Elements in GridView, here ,

put int count = (position + 1); in your GridView Adapter getView(..) method. It is callback method, called number of times to populate your Gridview. Starts from 0.

```
    int count = 0; // define count as global instance var.
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
...
count = position + 1;
...
}
```

count is what you want.

Comment: how can we get this value in our Activty file(Suppose in this example ExistingDetailedActivity).

Comment: i have written that, define count as a instance variable of ExistingDetailActivity class. like this,                                                             class ExistingDetailActivity{ int count=0; .... }